# using loop in GNU makefile

Tags: loops, makefile, llvm, llvm-clang

Can anyone help me figure out why am I not be bale to pass different versions of `.ll` files to `LLVM_OPT` here? Is there a way in makefile to extract each `basename` of those `$(SRC)` to pass to `opt`?

So the scenario is compiling `*.c` with `clang` and then applying `opt` with `$(CCC_OPT)` to each individual `*.ll` to transform them to `$file_Opt.ll`. At last, `clang` generate the backend `a.out` by linking all `$file_Opt.ll`.

```
BENCHMARK = $(shell basename `pwd`)
SRC := $(wildcard *.c) 
HEADERS := $(wildcard *.h)

# Actions
.PHONY: all  clean vclean
all: 
    $(ZCC) $(HEADERS) $(INCPATHS) $(SRC)  
    $(foreach var,$(SRC), $(CC_OPTS) $(CCC_OPTS) -S -o $(var)_llvmOpt.ll $(var).ll;)
    $(LCC) -v  *_llvmOpt.ll -lm
clean:
    rm -f a.out *.o *.a *.s *.i *.I

vclean:
    rm -f a.out *.o *.a *.s *.i *.I *.ll
```

## output:

```
opt: loop-wrap.c.ll: error: Could not open input file: No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: What about this isn't working exactly? What is the output from running `make`? What is `$(CC_OPTS)`? What is `$(CCC_OPTS)`? Does `$(CC_OPTS)` contain the actual command to run?

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. I am updating it. the issue is that from each `file.c`, I should extract the `file` part and then pass it to `opt`

Comment: Yeah, so, you do realize that's not *anywhere* in your original question, right? And not even explicitly asked in the updated question, right?

Comment: Well, the question is still valid. how to define certain loops in makefiles. Now I need to define another before the `action` section, but how...

Comment: Your use of `$(foreach)` is perfectly fine and correct. You haven't mentioned anything about another loop. You haven't shown an attempt at one. You haven't provided a failure or error or anything about how your other loop isn't working. So that's not part of the question you asked either.

Comment: Ok @EtanReisner. Just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices for removing the `.c` suffix from the filename.

You can use the [Text Function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) `patsubst` directly:

```
$(foreach var,$(patsubst %.c,%,$(SRC)),$(CC_OPTS) $(CCC_OPTS) -S -o $(var)_llvmOpt.ll $(var).ll;)
```

Or through a [Substitution Reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Substitution-Refs).

```
$(foreach var,$(SRC:.c=),$(CC_OPTS) $(CCC_OPTS) -S -o $(var)_llvmOpt.ll $(var).ll;)
```

Or, and this is arguably more correct, you could also use the [Functions for File Names](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#File-Name-Functions) function `basename` for this:

```
$(foreach var,$(basename $(SRC)),$(CC_OPTS) $(CCC_OPTS) -S -o $(var)_llvmOpt.ll $(var).ll;)
```

Comment: ahh, I should have done the third one myself at first!  Thanks @Etan